# Complement of non-deterministic finite automation

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

Given an NFA, is there a way to “take its complement” and obtain an NFA that recognizes the complement language?

Comment: Isn't this a dup of http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/13282/755?  The author is even the same.

Comment: @Gilles As D.W. points out, this is probably a duplicate question.  I agree that Yuval probably answered the question, but I don't think this question is useful for future visitors unless completely rewritten.